# How to set QListView rows height permanently

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qtableview

Unfortunately `QTableView.resizeRowsToContents()` sets the height of only those rows (or items) that are currently populating the `TableView`. With a first `model`'s reset() or update the `QTableView`'s row's heights switch back to some default value (which seems to be around 32 px high).
Most of the time this default row height is unnecessarily high leaving a lot of valuable screen space unfilled. 
How to apply the change to the row height permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out two ways to permanently set the rows height, you either have to use SizeHintRole in your model or implement the sizeHint method in a QStyledItemDelegate. Here's what the code will look like:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys


class ListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, data=[], parent=None):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.data)

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            value = self.data[row]
            return value

# ==============Comment if you're using delegate===============
        if role == Qt.SizeHintRole:
            return QSize(100, 75)
# =============================================================


class ListDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QSize(100, 20)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
listview = QListView()
model = ListModel([12, 15, 19])
listview.setModel(model)

# =============uncomment to use delegate=====================
# delegate = ListDelegate()
# listview.setItemDelegate(delegate)
# ============================================================

listview.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```